# C: Call close() in if condition

Tags: c

Generally,

I read lot of code which always used following snippet to check if close `fd` successfully

```c
// code A
int result = close(some_fd);
if ( result == -1)
  perror("close error");
```

I'd like to simplify above code

```c
//code B
if ( close(some_fd) == -1 )
  perror("close error");
```

Above snippet can be executed and if has error,

then "close error" also can be display normally.

AFAIK, `if (conditions)` which *conditions* will be *r-value*,

so that should mean `( close(some_fd) == -1 )` just **temporary**

Dose `close(some_fd)` really execute normally when I call it in *if condition*?

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it?

Comment: What do you mean with "just temporary"?

Comment: Hi @klutt: yes,I mean  with "just temporary"

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I've modified my article, my question is "Code A" equivalent to "Code B"?

Comment: Both are correct and are executed normally, you can use the first option if you need to use the return value from close() later, but it's only zero or -1, so the second one is more practical.

Comment: Hi @AlbertoPires: Ok, I got it. Thanks very much. Could write your message to answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely invoke close inside the `if`.

In fact, you're a right when you say that the r-value is temporary, as it represents a value which is stored into a temporary memory address, just used to be assigned to a l-value.

However, in your case, what it's stored "temporarly" is the whole condition value, which means the return value of `close(fd)` fuction comparared to `-1`. Therefore, the `close` will be executed as expected, and its effects is not temporary.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct and are executed normally, you can use the first option if you need to use the return value from close() later, but it's only zero or -1, so in this case the second one is more practical.